# get the rotation of a face

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh, mathematics

I'm trying to get the rotation of bmeshs face. Unfortunately following function doesn't work:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

plane = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(rotation = (2,1,1))

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

mesh_obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = mesh_obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:
    print(face.rotation)  # doesn't work
```

I'd like to get the vector (2,1,1) printed out, how can this work?

Comment: transformation info are stored on the object level, mesh doesn't have that stored ( only location ) you may get the face normal if that help

Comment: It doesn't work since a bmesh face https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace _unfortunately_ has no rotation property.